# Why is there a growing time delaying when getting values from redis using go-redis?

Tags: go, redis, go-redis

If you get a relatively large value (example 100kb) out of `redis` concurrently with a high amount of go routines, you see a consistantly increasing latency. Why is that and how can it be handled?

Furthermore, if you run multiple instances of the script (even on different clients so not cpu bound), you see the latency increasing faster. So each additional client is slowing down all other clients.

This should not happen at this small scale on redis right? From `redis-benchmark` It can handle 100k connections at a huge throughput. I am doing 1-5 connections.

Here are some results of running the script on just a single client, followed by the script.

```
0: time: 0ms, val size: 100000
1: time: 37ms, val size: 100000
12: time: 37ms, val size: 100000
13: time: 37ms, val size: 100000
38: time: 37ms, val size: 100000
133: time: 97ms, val size: 100000
145: time: 97ms, val size: 100000
77: time: 97ms, val size: 100000
.
.
.
979: time: 235ms, val size: 100000
914: time: 236ms, val size: 100000
957: time: 232ms, val size: 100000
980: time: 235ms, val size: 100000
958: time: 235ms, val size: 100000
954: time: 236ms, val size: 100000
913: time: 236ms, val size: 100000
921: time: 236ms, val size: 100000
961: time: 236ms, val size: 100000
976: time: 236ms, val size: 100000
```

```golang
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "context"
    "time"
    "strings"
    "github.com/redis/go-redis/v9"
)

var ctx = context.Background()

func main() {
    // Create a new Redis client
    rdb := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr:     "localhost:6379",
        DB:       5,
    })
    // Store a 100k value in Redis
    key := "some:test:key"
    value := strings.Repeat("a", 100000)
    err := rdb.Set(ctx, key, value, 0).Err()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to set value:", err)
        return
    }
    // Get the value asynchronously 500 times, log the time it takes for each
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            t1 := time.Now()
            val, err := rdb.Get(ctx, key).Result()
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Failed to get value:", err)
                return
            }
            t2 := time.Now()
            fmt.Printf("%d: time: %vms, val size: %d\n", i, t2.Sub(t1).Milliseconds(), len(val))
        }(i)
    }
    // Wait for a while to ensure all goroutines have finished
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a definitive answer, I see the same slowdown as you, however, a couple of things may help explain things.

First, `t1` is oddly placed. It doesn't allow you to measure the time each goroutine spends, but rather the time the from when the first `t1` was created to when the goroutine ends. Remember that `go func(){}()` only schedules a goroutine, it will run later. So `t1` will probably not vary much for those 1000 iterations.

The second thing is that with a 1000 concurrent goroutines, bound almost completely to TCP i/o, the scheduler is probably going crazy. Adding a semaphore to your code allows each goroutine to complete in ~1ms, in the same timespan as the original code.

My guess is that redis is idling when your code runs, but the scheduler is being thrashed.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "time"

    "github.com/redis/go-redis/v9"
)

var ctx = context.Background()

func main() {
    // Create a semaphore using a buffered channel
    sem := make(chan struct{}, 5)
    // Create a new Redis client
    rdb := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr: "localhost:6379",
        DB:   5,
    })
    // Store a 100k value in Redis
    key := "some:test:key"
    value := strings.Repeat("a", 100000)
    err := rdb.Set(ctx, key, value, 0).Err()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to set value:", err)
        return
    }

    // Get the value asynchronously 500 times, log the time it takes for each
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            // aquire semaphore
            sem <- struct{}{}
            defer func() {
                // release semaphore
                <-sem
            }()
            t1 := time.Now()
            val, err := rdb.Get(ctx, key).Result()
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Failed to get value:", err)
                return
            }
            t2 := time.Now()
            fmt.Printf("%d: time: %vμs, val size: %d\n", i, t2.Sub(t1).Microseconds(), len(val))
        }(i)
    }

    // Wait for a while to ensure all goroutines have finished
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
}
```

Yields

```
…
991: time: 907μs, val size: 100000
992: time: 835μs, val size: 100000
993: time: 905μs, val size: 100000
994: time: 875μs, val size: 100000
995: time: 783μs, val size: 100000
996: time: 829μs, val size: 100000
997: time: 850μs, val size: 100000
853: time: 775μs, val size: 100000
998: time: 2117μs, val size: 100000
852: time: 2187μs, val size: 100000
842: time: 1957μs, val size: 100000
858: time: 1268μs, val size: 100000
854: time: 890μs, val size: 100000
859: time: 1641μs, val size: 100000
855: time: 1421μs, val size: 100000
```

Obviously I measure different things, but from a goroutine standpoint, there's no latency when talking to redis.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer.  Yeah I noticed the placement of t1 was odd and moved it to inside the goroutine. I thought it was an error, but surprisingly, it didnt really make a difference, so i didnt change it on here (i did now). Im not sure what your code does, are you reading from redis with some code hidden, or are you testing just the scheduler time? I dont think the scheduler is my problem, since my script shows the redis problem with constant goroutines. In my use case, I have a higher client count with less goroutines per client, but for a longer time, so the issue builds up.

Comment: My code answer was a diff, but I've inlined the whole example now.

When you say "constant" goroutines, are you referring to 1000 in your code example? I ran my example 100.000 times without any build-up.